# Angular scope filling in email data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, email

SO I have a function within my form and using angular where the email works, but am having an issue getting it to populate the body of the email. In addition, is there a way to force the 'from' part of the email even if it is technically emailed from the users own client?

My code is shown below for what I have:

Controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('mbapp')
    .controller('StepsController', StepsController, ['$scope']);

  /** @ngInject */
  function StepsController($scope, $timeout, webDevTec, toastr) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.awesomeThings = [];
    vm.classAnimation = '';
    vm.creationDate = 1467136913872;
    vm.showToastr = showToastr;

    activate();

    function activate() {
      getWebDevTec();
      $timeout(function() {
        vm.classAnimation = 'rubberBand';
      }, 4000);
    }

    $scope.Subject = "Moneyball Problem Phase Worksheet"
    $scope.bodyText = {
        hypCriteria: ""
    };

    $scope.mailLink = "mailto:" + $scope.emailId + "?subject=" + $scope.Subject + '&body=' + $scope.bodyText;


    function showToastr() {
      toastr.info('Fork <a href="https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular" target="_blank"><b>generator-gulp-angular</b></a>');
      vm.classAnimation = '';
    }

    function getWebDevTec() {
      vm.awesomeThings = webDevTec.getTec();

      angular.forEach(vm.awesomeThings, function(awesomeThing) {
        awesomeThing.rank = Math.random();
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

And my view (html):

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="font-family: Segoe UI; padding: 0;">
    <div style="background-color: #0070c0; min-height:100px;">
        <h1 style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 24px; padding-left:20px; padding-top: 30px;">Problem Phase Worksheet:</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color: #0070c0; font-size: 18px;">Inputs</span>
            </div>          
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="criteria" style="font-size: 14px;">Criteria:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="criteria" ng-model="criteria" style="font-size: 14px;" placeholder="(e.g. more than 80%)">
            </div>              
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="customer" style="font-size: 14px;">Customer:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer" ng-model="customer" style="font-size: 14px;" placeholder="(e.g. enterprise system admins)">
                <!-- <p style="font-size: 12px;">(e.g. Infrastructure admins, network engineer, etc..)</p>   -->      
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="task" style="font-size: 14px;">Job to be Done:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task" ng-model="task" style="font-size: 14px;" placeholder="(e.g. keeping servers up to date)">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="problem" style="font-size: 14px;">Problem:  <a href="#criteriaModal" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: #afabab;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></label>          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="problem" ng-model="problem" style="font-size: 14px;" placeholder="(e.g. it takes to long (24+ hours) )">
            </div>  
        </div>  
        <!-- criteriaModal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="criteriaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="criteriaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                            &times;
                        </button>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean consequat odio vel fermentum faucibus. Phasellus vestibulum, justo sed vestibulum bibendum, risus mauris congue nisi, et iaculis ipsum nisl a turpis. Vivamus et purus diam. Proin sagittis nisl eu porttitor posuere. Phasellus feugiat nec elit et hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque blandit a quam eget malesuada. Cras lobortis augue nibh, a feugiat justo consequat ac. In sit amet pulvinar massa. In maximus, justo eget elementum laoreet, lacus nunc molestie lectus, at congue neque nisl quis est. Nam non laoreet mauris. Phasellus non ullamcorper libero. Duis dapibus ornare arcu in fringilla. Curabitur molestie ex eu nunc ultricies, id pharetra nisl semper.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" data-dismiss="modal" value="okay">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->        
        <div class="col-md-6">   
            <div> 
                <span style="color: #0070c0; font-size: 18px;">Examples</span>
                <a ng-href="{{mailLink}}" target="_self" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right; font-size: 18px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>  Email
                </a>
            </div>              
            <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 15px; margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">       
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">HYPOTHESIS:</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;" id="hypCriteria">We believe that <span>{{ criteria || '[criteria]' }}</span> of <span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> are most frustrated about <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> because <span>{{ problem || '[problem]' }}</span>.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">CUSTOMER SCREENING CRITERIA:</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">We are looking for <span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> who are regularly involved in <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>.</p>
                </div> 
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">SCREENER:</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">How often do you <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> in your daily job?</p>
                </div>    
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">CUSTOMER INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">Tell me about the last time when you were <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>?</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">What are the major challenges with <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>?</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">On a scale of 0-10, how frustrating are these problems? Why?</p>            
                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">If you could wave a magic wand and be able to do anything about <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> in your daily job, what would it be?</p>
                </div>  
            </div>          
        </div>                         
    </form>
</div>
```

Almost forgot, I am only trying to email the data in this div (this div has static text and text injected from the form filled from the other section of the page):

```
<div class="col-md-6">   
    <div> 
        <span style="color: #0070c0; font-size: 18px;">Examples</span>
        <a ng-href="{{mailLink}}" target="_self" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right; font-size: 18px;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>  Email
        </a>
    </div>              
    <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 15px; margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">       
        <div>
            <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">HYPOTHESIS:</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;" id="hypCriteria">We believe that <span>{{ criteria || '[criteria]' }}</span> of <span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> are most frustrated about <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> because <span>{{ problem || '[problem]' }}</span>.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">CUSTOMER SCREENING CRITERIA:</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">We are looking for <span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> who are regularly involved in <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>.</p>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">SCREENER:</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">How often do you <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> in your daily job?</p>
        </div>    
        <div>
            <p style="font-size: 12px; color: #afabab;">CUSTOMER INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">Tell me about the last time when you were <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>?</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">What are the major challenges with <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span>?</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">On a scale of 0-10, how frustrating are these problems? Why?</p>            
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">If you could wave a magic wand and be able to do anything about <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[task]' }}</span> in your daily job, what would it be?</p>
        </div>  
    </div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can not handle anything in email client. All you can do is to pass subject, body, cc, bcc like you already did.